# def __bool__ oriented object programming python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I try to create a subclass of customer who comes often to a restaurant. Then, because of their budget they can maybe not come to the restaurant. I decided to use the `__bool__` statement provided by Python but it always gives me true as output.

I used the following code:

```
prices_drink = {"milkshake": 5,"frappucino": 4, "water": 2,"coffee": 3, "soda": 3, "tea": 3}
prices_food = {"sandwich": 2, "cookie": 2, "pie": 3,"muffin": 3}

class Customer (object):
    def __init__(self, id, budget):
        self.id = id
        self.budget = budget

class Recurrent(Customer):
    def __init__(self, id, budget):
        self.id = id
        self.budget = budget

    def __bool__(self):
        if self.budget <= max(prices_drink.values()) + max(prices_food.values()):
            return False
        return True

    def description(self):
        print(f"This is Customer {self.id}. They come here often. Can he buy? {bool(Recurrent)}")

customer2 = Recurrent(123456, 5)
customer2.description()
```

What is the solution?

Comment: You want to call `bool(self)`, not `bool(Recurrent)`. Just like you used `self.id` and not `Recurrent.id`.

Comment: BTW, using `__bool__` for this is probably not a good idea. Why not just have a method named `has_enough_budget()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call bool on Recurrent you call it on the class, not the object.

If you need to do it the way you did it for school, thats okay. But I would suggest to use method names that make sense and refactor id to customer_id as id is a built-in function in python

And as us are using a parent class you can use super to call the constructor of the super class and forward the arguments to it.

For example:

```
prices_drink = {"milkshake": 5, "frappucino": 4, "water": 2, "coffee": 3, "soda": 3, "tea": 3}
prices_food = {"sandwich": 2, "cookie": 2, "pie": 3, "muffin": 3}


class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self, customer_id, budget):
        self.customer_id = customer_id
        self.budget = budget


class Recurrent(Customer):
    def __init__(self, customer_id, budget):
        super().__init__(customer_id, budget)

    def is_in_budget(self):
        if self.budget <= max(prices_drink.values()) + max(prices_food.values()):
            return False
        return True

    def print_customer_liquidity(self):
        print(
            f'This is Customer {self.customer_id}.'
            f' They come here often. Can he buy ? {self.is_in_budget()}'
        )


customer2 = Recurrent(123456, 5)
customer2.print_customer_liquidity()
```